# Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \left[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right]$ given by $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \left[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right]$ a function given by $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$. Determine if $f$ is injective, surjective or bijective.

Graphically, we can see that the function is not injective. I have been trying to show that if $a,b\in \mathbb{R}, f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$, but I can't conclude that $f$ is not injective using simple algebra. For another hand, to see the surjectivity, I need to prove that for all $y \in \left[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right]$ exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(x)=y$. But I have problems with the algebra again. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Are there two solutions to $\frac{x}{x^2+1}=\frac25$? If so, the function is not injective.

Can you solve $\frac{x}{x^2+1}=\frac12$ and $\frac{x}{x^2+1}=-\frac12$? Then $\frac12$ and $-\frac12$ are in the range. And as this is a continuous function, so is every value $y$ in between.

Answer (score 1):

The best way will nevertheless be to sketch a rough graph, and answer the question.

By your method,

$\frac{x}{{x^2 + 1}} = \frac{y}{{y^2 + 1}}$

$xy^2 + x = yx^2 + y$

$xy(y-x) + (x-y) = 0$

$(xy-1)(x-y)=0$

Since, x=y is not the only solution, it's not a one-one function (or injective)

For surjective checking, we know that,

$f'(x) = \frac{(1+x^2)-2x^2}{{(1+x^2)}^2}$

$f'(x) = \frac{1-x^2}{{(1+x^2)}^2}$

maxima and minima occur at 1 and -1

f(1) = 1/2 -->maxima,
f(-1) = -1/2--> minima

so, all values lie between [-0.5,0.5]

Answer (score 1):

So we have the function $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
Now, suppose f(a)=f(b).

We get,

$$\frac{a}{1+a^2}=\frac{b}{1+b^2}$$

$$\implies a(1+b^2)=b(1+a^2)$$
$$\implies ab(b-a)=(b-a)$$
$$\implies a=\frac{1}{b}$$

Observe that for f(a)=f(b), a$\ne$b. Hence, the function f(x) is not injective.

For subjectivity, if we can show that the range of f(x) equals the codomain of the function, then we can show that it is indeed surjective. So, let f(x)=y.

We have, $$y=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
Find x=f(y)

We get, $$x=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4y^2}}{y}$$
$\implies f(y)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{y}$

We know that, $1-4y^2\ge0$
$$\implies -\frac{1}{2} \le y \le \frac{1}{2}$$

You may ask me, what about the y in denominator in f(y). Well, the function f(x) already has 0 included in its domain which means its defined for x=0. Hence, we observe that the range is indeed equal to the codomain, so f(x) is surjective.
Hence, f(x) is not injective, but it is surjective.